# Ubicar uno al lado del otro elementos de LI con imagenes

Tags: css, lista, flexbox

[image: Necesitaria ordenar Brasil y Caribe (por ejemplo) uno al lado del otro con sus respectivas fotos]Buenas tardes. Estoy empezando a aprender css pero me trabé con una duda que no logro resolver por mi cuenta..
Necesito poner en linea una al lado de otra elementos de una LIST que contienen imágenes (destinos nacionales y destinos internacionales), cuando creo las clases y le pido que se acomoden inline no se hacen de esta manera..
Pego mi código para saber como lo harian!
Desde ya muchas gracias.

HTML:

```
  <section>
           <h1>Las mejores recomendaciones para elegir destino</h1>
                <h3>A donde queres viajar?</h3>
                <h4>Cliqueá tu destino en mente y empezá a armar tu idea de viaje</h4>
                <ul class="destinos">
                    <li>Destinos internacionales &#128506;</li>
                 </ul>
                 <ol class="destinos-int" >
                        <li class="destinos-intl"><a href="https://www.skyscanner.es/noticias/10-cosas-increibles-para-hacer-en-brasil">Brasil</a></li>
                        <figure><img src="./Imagenes/pexels-athena-1804177.jpg"  height= "250" alt="Imagen del cristo en Rio"><figcaption>Atardecer en el Cristo de Rio.</figcaption></figure>
                        <li class="destinos-intl"><a href="https://paquetes.iberojet.com/blog/consejos-para-viajar-caribe">Caribe</a></li>
                        <figure><img src="./Imagenes/pexels-lina-kivaka-4371607.jpg" height= "250" alt="Imagen de playa"><figcaption>Relax en la playa</figcaption></figure>
                        <li class="destinos-intl"><a href="https://guias-viajar.com/consejos-viajar-por-tu-cuenta/guia-viajar-europa/">Europa</a></li>
                        <figure><img src="./Imagenes/pexels-sid-ali-2028885.jpg"  height= "250" alt="Londres un día lluvioso"><figcaption>Londres en un día lluvioso.</figcaption></figure>
                        <li class="destinos-intl"><a href="https://viajandoporahi.com/consejos-para-viajar-al-sudeste-asiatico/">Sudeste Asiático</a></li>
                        <figure><img src="./Imagenes/pexels-alexandr-podvalny-2070485.jpg"  height= "250" alt="Imagen del sudeste asiático"><figcaption>Sudeste asiático y sus templos</figcaption></figure>
                    </ol>

    <div></div>
                <ul><li class="destinos">Destinos Nacionales </li>
                </ul>
                 <ol>
                     <li class="destinos-intl"><a href="https://recorriendo.com/2015/08/02/10-lugares-que-debes-visitar-en-la-patagonia-argentina/">Patagonia</a></li>
                     <figure><img src="./Imagenes/pexels-palu-malerba-4911155.jpg"  height= "250" alt="Imagen de mates en la Patagonia Argentina"><figcaption>Mates en la Patagonia Argentina.</figcaption></figure>
                     <li class="destinos-intl"><a href="https://www.viator.com/es-AR/Northwest-Argentina/d30283">Norte Argentino</a></li>
                     <figure><img src="./Imagenes/pexels-tiago-tins-3428290.jpg"  height= "250" alt="Imagen de niño del norte"><figcaption>Cultura norteña</figcaption></figure>
                     <li class="destinos-intl"><a  href="https://www.viajablog.com/consejos-practicos-para-viajar-a-las-cataratas-de-iguazu/">Cataratas</a></li>
                     <figure><img src="./Imagenes/pexels-tomas-anunziata-695214.jpg"  height= "250" alt="imagen de las Cataratas del Iguazú"><figcaption>Una de las 7 maravillas naturales del mundo</figcaption></figure>
                 </ol>
                 <ul>
                    <p class="destinos"> Otros destinos que ofrecemos
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://aventurateaviajar.com/noticias/2020-08-20/los-12-mejores-destinos-para-viajar-en-2021/"> que no te podes perder </a>
                      </p>
                
                 <li><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5493512336517"> No se a donde viajar y quiero hablar por WhatsApp con un agente de viajes.</a>
                </li>
            </section>
```